# OpenCV Android crashes on Imgproc.cvtColor()

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV4Android.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.camtime/com.fognature.develop.smp.CameraActivity}:
>   CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739:
>   error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
>                                                                            ]
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                                                                             Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739:
>   error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
>                                                                            ]
>                                                                                at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_1(Native Method)
>                                                                                at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:4598)
>                                                                                at
>   com.fognature.develop.smp.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:108)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
>                                                                                 ... 10 more

On this code part:

```
Mat sec;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sec = new Mat();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()


+File.separator+"SMP"+File.separator+getIntent().getStringExtra("c_name")+File.separator+getIntent().getStringExtra("last_photo"));
                sec = Highgui.imread(photo.getAbsolutePath());
                Imgproc.cvtColor(sec, sec, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        }
```

It always crash on **Imgproc.cvtColor(sec, sec, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error states that :

> error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int) ]

which generally means that:

- When you are trying to convert `RGBA2GRAY`, then the input Mat `sec` in this case has Only 1 channel. You can confirm this by logging the `sec.channels()` just after reading it.
- It is also possible that, input Mat was empty or corrupted, to confirm you may check `sec.width`, `sec.height`, `sec.depth`, etc attributes to assure that it was loaded properly.

Comment: Yeah, width and height of Mat are 0